# Querying ElasticSearch - Multiple terms matched on differing times

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Have been wracking my brain on how to do this, but cannot come up with a solution. Hoping stack can help.

I have a situation where an identifier (let's call it object id - OID) is:

**1) Used to track a chain of transactions;
2) Not guaranteed to be unique outside of a 5 minute interval.**

In English " I want to fetch all documents that: (have oid1 with data between time x and y) OR (have oid2 with data between time w and z) OR ...."

Because I am dealing with a lot of data (and want to avoid doing 1 query per OID), What I would like to do is get a list of OIDs, set a time limit for each one, and then query ES at once. What I thought I could do is:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "oid": "12ac419512ac4195"
          },

          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "from": "2019-01-04T21:31:00.000Z",
              "to": "2019-01-04T21:34:00.000Z"
            }
          }

        },

        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "oid": "34df261834df2618"
          },

          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "from": "2019-01-04T21:35:00.000Z",
              "to": "2019-01-04T21:40:00.000Z"
            }
          }

        }

      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as I remove the time("I want to fetch oid1 or oid2 or oid2"), but with the time range it seems to make ES not happy.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck to one query per OID.

Comment: Check out the second example here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html

On mobile so can't format

Answer (score 0):

You need another sub level of bool + must clause to tie the match + range together.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "oid": "12ac419512ac4195"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "startTime": {
                    "from": "2019-01-04T21:31:00.000Z",
                    "to": "2019-01-04T21:34:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "oid": "34df261834df2618"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "startTime": {
                    "from": "2019-01-04T21:35:00.000Z",
                    "to": "2019-01-04T21:40:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```